# How to query a custom made join table many-to-many relationship in Typeorm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

With the help of Typeorm I made the following two database entities, *users* and *tenants*, which are connected bi-directionally with the help of a custom made join table, *users_tenants*. The reason I am using a custom join table is because I want to extend the custom join table with extra fields.

The *users* entity:

```
@Entity('users')
export default class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id!: string;

    @Column({
        length: 32,
        nullable: false,
    })
    firstName!: string;

    @Column({
        length: 32,
        nullable: false,
    })
    lastName!: string;

    @OneToMany(() => UserTenant, (userTenant) => userTenant.user)
    userTenants!: UserTenant[];

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp with time zone' })
    createdAt!: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp with time zone' })
    updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

---

The *tenants* entity:

```
@Entity('tenants')
export default class Tenant extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id!: string;

    @Column({
        length: 32,
        nullable: false,
    })
    name!: string;

    @Column({
        length: 200,
        nullable: false,
    })
    description!: string;

    @OneToMany(() => UserTenant, (userTenant) => userTenant.tenant)
    userTenants!: UserTenant[];

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp with time zone' })
    createdAt!: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp with time zone' })
    updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

---

The custom join table *users_tenants*:

```
@Entity('users_tenants')
@Index(['userId', 'tenantId'], { unique: true })
export default class UserTenant extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id!: string;

    @Column()
    userId!: string;

    @Column()
    tenantId!: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.userTenants, {
        nullable: false,
        eager: true,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
    user!: User;

    @ManyToOne(() => Tenant, (tenant) => tenant.userTenants, {
        nullable: false,
        eager: true,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'tenantId' })
    tenant!: Tenant;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp with time zone' })
    createdAt!: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp with time zone' })
    updatedAt!: Date;
 }
```

---

My goal is to query the database which results in a structure like this: `tenant ---> list of users`. So I try to query the database with the following code:

```
const tenant = await database.collections.Tenant?.findOne({
    relations: ['userTenants', 'userTenants.user'],
    where: {
        id,
    },
});
```

---

Which results in the following output:

```
{
    "id": "97754b60-ca22-47d7-b611-49ac4d81e4af",
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test description",
    "createdAt": "2021-02-01T19:20:43.185Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T19:20:43.185Z",
    "userTenants": [
        {
            "id": "6b32e4de-23f4-4cef-bd1d-34359e7d9f9b",
            "userId": "6350db80-770b-4997-8ba4-d2f194f7b16f",
            "tenantId": "97754b60-ca22-47d7-b611-49ac4d81e4af",
            "createdAt": "2021-02-02T17:45:41.660Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-02-02T17:45:41.660Z",
            "user": {
                "id": "6350db80-770b-4997-8ba4-d2f194f7b16f",
                "firstName": "User",
                "lastName": "Userlast",
                "createdAt": "2021-02-02T17:45:07.372Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-02-02T17:45:07.372Z"
            },
            "tenant": {
                "id": "97754b60-ca22-47d7-b611-49ac4d81e4af",
                "name": "test",
                "description": "test description",
                "createdAt": "2021-02-01T19:20:43.185Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T19:20:43.185Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

The problem with this output is that a list of user-tenant relationships are returned and not a list of users that belong to that tenant. When this would be a simple *one to many* relationship I can recieve the output as follows:

```
{
    "id": "97754b60-ca22-47d7-b611-49ac4d81e4af",
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test description",
    "createdAt": "2021-02-01T19:20:43.185Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T19:20:43.185Z",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "6350db80-770b-4997-8ba4-d2f194f7b16f",
            "firstName": "User",
            "lastName": "Userlast",
            "createdAt": "2021-02-02T17:45:07.372Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-02-02T17:45:07.372Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Question:** How do I have to perform the query (with the help of Typeorm) so data in a custom made bi-directional join table is returned like the structure above?